# How to show a highlighted label when The mouse is on widget

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, python-3.7

I need to know how to make a highlighted label(or small box )appears when the mouse is on widget like when you are using browser and put the mouse on (reload/back/etc...) button a small box will appear and tell you what this button do
and i want that for any widget not only widgets on toolbar

Comment: [QWidget.setToolTip](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#toolTip-prop).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As the comment of @ekhumoro says
setToolTip is the solution